# How to view VS 2019 Class Diagram, error "URI formats are not supported"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, class-diagram

#### Scenario:

I'm using VS 2019 Enterprise (coding in C#) and added the Class Designer. I can create a class diagram

> (`add`, `add new item`, `class diagram`);

#### Problem:

when I try to open it I get an error starting, **URI formats are not supported**. The only solution I found was for VS 2012 which said to change the Website from `IIS` Express to "Use Visual Studio Development Server". I don't see that option listed. Can you help resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

#### To Change IIS Express To Local IIS use this:

[Switch IIS Express To Local IIS](http://doc.fireflymigration.com/switch-iis-express-to-local-iis.html)

#### If doesn't have a Web tab you should know:

ASP.NET core projects use an external file (properties\launchsettings.json) to store "profiles" containing launch information. To enable local IIS:

#### And do this:

1. R-click on the project and choose properties
2. Select the "Debug" tab
3. Click the New button to create a new profile and give it a name: Something like Local IIS
4. In the Launch dropdown change it from "Executable" to "IIS"
5. Check the Launch browser option
6. Add the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with a value of Development
7. Ctrl+S to save changes

[image]
8. The newly created profile will appear in the debug dropdown. Select it as the profile to run.

Note that IIS requires running Visual Studio as an administrator, and you need to make sure you check the optional "Development time IIS support" when you installed Visual Studio (you can modify your existing install be rerunning the Visual Studio Installer and add this if you haven't done so already).

[image]

Comment: I only see Property Pages, and it doesn't have a Web tab. Here is what I see: https://mypages.valdosta.edu/dgibson/prop.jpg

Comment: Answer edited (added answer of when you can't see web tab)

Comment: thanks for directions, I'll try tomorrow when in office.

Comment: I would be happy if tomorrow announce the result.